# php sort by key multidimentional array

Tags: php, sorting

Supposed I have an array of

```
array(8) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'Peter' =>
    int(4)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'Piper' =>
    int(4)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'picked' =>
    int(4)
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    'peck' =>
    int(4)
  }
  [4] =>
  array(1) {
    'pickled' =>
    int(4)
  }
```

How can I sort this multidimentional array by key example (Peter). I tried using

```
ksort($arr);
```

but it just return a boolean

The output that I want

```
array(8) {
      [0] =>
      array(1) {
        'peck' =>
        int(4)
      }
      [1] =>
      array(1) {
        'Peter' =>
        int(4)
      }
      [2] =>
      array(1) {
        'picked' =>
        int(4)
      }
      [3] =>
      array(1) {
        'pickled' =>
        int(4)
      }
      [4] =>
      array(1) {
        'piper' =>
        int(4)
    }
```

the array should be sorted by key and in ascending order.

Comment: print your array using print_r($arr) function and show your output here

Comment: I tried different functions like array_multisort, ksort but it just return a bolean of true

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: What is the expected output and why is it that way? I don't understand ***How can I sort this multidimentional array by key example (Peter).***

Comment: check the edited questiopn

Answer (score 1):

Sort with usort like this, check the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2fa26d7d28828d022593174f95ab13238db1cf3b)

```
usort($array,function($a,$b){
    return strcmp(strtolower(key($a)),strtolower(key($b)));
});
```

Comment: @Beginner check the demo in the answer.

Comment: why peter is on the first index it should be peck

Comment: For upper case `P` is less than lower case `p`

Comment: Is it possible to sort it regardless of its case? i just want to display it on alphabetical order

Comment: @Beginner yes, check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

The `ksort()` method does an in-place sort. So while it only returns a boolean (as you correctly state), it mutates the values inside `$arr` to be in the sorted order. Note that based on your expected output, it looks like you want to do a case insensitive search. For that, you need to use the `SORT_FLAG_CASE` sort flag. So, instead of calling `ksort($arr)`, you instead want to use `ksort($arr, SORT_FLAG_CASE)`. You can see how `ksort()` uses sort flags, in the [`sort()` method's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
$temp = array_map(function($a){
    return key($a); // fetching all the keys
}, $arr);
natcasesort($temp); // sorting values case insensitive
$result = [];
// logic of sorting by other array
foreach($temp as $v){
    foreach($arr as $v1){
        if($v == key($v1)){
            $result[] = $v1;
            break;
        }        
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8I2sL)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [peck] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Peter] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [picked] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pickled] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Piper] => 4
        )

)
```